Non-graphical way to change mouse settings on MacOS circa Sonoma
I have to regularly change my mouse settings on my MBP when switching between walking on a treadmill and using my standing desk. I want to automate these changes to a script of some sort. Maybe something I can pull up with Raycast. I want to change mouse sensitivity and acceleration. I found that I can change the saved settings with:
   defaults write 'Apple Global Domain' com.apple.mouse.linear 0
   defaults write 'Apple Global Domain' com.apple.mouse.scaling 0.5

But, those do not affect the active values, only the saved preferences.
I tried playing around with AppleScript for the first time in my life only to find that it really doesn't work to use scripts such as these:
-- Open System Preferences
tell application "System Settings" to activate

-- Attempt to change settings using System Events
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Settings"
        try
            -- Open the "Mouse" pane
            click menu item "Mouse" of menu "View" of menu bar 1
            delay 2
            -- set value of slider "Tracking speed" to 2
            -- delay 2
            -- click button "Advanced..."
            -- press button "Advanced..."
            set value of slider "Pointer acceleration" to off
        on error theError
            display dialog ("Sorry, an error occurred")
        end try
    end tell
end tell

It seems like support for AppleScript is a dying thing.
After searching for other approaches, I have come up short. Anyone have any suggestions?

This seems more appropriate to Apple specific site : [apple.se]. Good luck.

The defaults are cached, so the process usually needs need to be restarted for it read in the new values.  As for scripting the UI, you need to specify the complete hierarchy of the UI element.  For example, to bring up the pointer acceleration sheet from the mouse settings window in Sonoma, it would be click button 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of group 2 of splitter group 1 of group 1 of window 1 (yeah, GUI scripting is not for the faint of heart).  I haven't had any luck setting values directly, so you would also need to do something like use key codes to adjust the controls.

Thanks, @shellter! I knew there was a better forum, but my "logical" search engine could not remember nor could I find it searching for a meaningful name. I think a bookmark is in order!

Thanks for the comment @red_menace! You have succeeded in scaring me away from ever trying such a thing in AppleScript again! I hate undocumented secrets like these, where you either have to hack at something to try to figure it out or have some deep insider knowledge. And, of course, one only ends up with a script that works until the next OS update with a breaking GUI change! I appreciate the time you put into commenting.

Reload the prefs this way :
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SystemAdministration.framework/Resources/activateSettings -u 
with applescript :
do shell script "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SystemAdministration.framework/Resources/activateSettings -u"


Thanks @Chino22! The first one worked fine for my needs. If I actually had an otherwise working AppleScript, the second might have been useful. But I'm all set now. Thanks for your time!
